# how to obtain specific "key" from json stringify (my case)?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to obtain "class" key on this json :

var data = [{"loc":[7.876110076904297,48.79586219787598,577.145938873291,427.3995780944824],"class":"low","score":0.752582848072052}]

If I try to `console.log(data)` it return "object, Object"

If I try to

```
var json : json.stringify(data)
console.log(json)
```

the result is

```
[{"loc":[7.876110076904297,48.79586219787598,577.145938873291,427.3995780944824],"class":"low","score":0.752582848072052}]
```

I already to map it but failed

```
var json = json.stringify(data)
var string = map.json(loc => loc.class)
console.log(string)
```

the result is "map.json is not a function"

I try to parse it but console show error

```
var json = json.parse(data)
```

the result is error

If I do this

```
var json = json.stringify(data)
console.log(json[5])
```

console return l, i guess this is 5th word on the var data

How I can get "class" key?
or do I need to count the word one by one, if yes how to know the specific word length on "class" key?

Answer (score 2):

The `JSON.stringify` method takes a *usable data structure* and converts it to a **string**.

The string is fantastic for storing (e.g. in localStorage) or transmitting over the network (e.g. in an Ajax request).

It is useless for working with.

Work with your original data structure instead.

```js
var data = [{
  "loc": [7.876110076904297, 48.79586219787598, 577.145938873291, 427.3995780944824],
  "class": "low",
  "score": 0.752582848072052
}]

const object = data[0];
const value = object.class;
console.log(value);
```

Comment: hi, I already try your code. It works on my other test. but this var data test, the result on console is "undefined".
Is there any way?

Comment: @ianzzz — `data` is copy/pasted from your question. I can't tell why it doesn't work on some other code you haven't shared with us.

Answer (score 1):

The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results.

```js
const data = [{"loc":[7.876110076904297,48.79586219787598,577.145938873291,427.3995780944824],"class":"low","score":0.752582848072052}];

const classes = data.map(loc => loc.class);
console.log(classes)
```

It seems like your array only contain just one object, so if instead of an array you just want the class value, you can just reference it.

```js
const data = [{"loc":[7.876110076904297,48.79586219787598,577.145938873291,427.3995780944824],"class":"low","score":0.752582848072052}];

const res = data[0].class;
console.log(res)
```

Comment: hi, I already try your code. It works on my other test. but this var data test, the result on console is "undefined". Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{"loc":[7.876110076904297,48.79586219787598,577.145938873291,427.3995780944824],"class":"low","score":0.752582848072052}]
console.log(data[0].class)
var a= data[0].class;
alert(JSON.stringify(a))
```

you can get class data from it in this way

```
var data = [{"loc":[7.876110076904297,48.79586219787598,577.145938873291,427.3995780944824],"class":"low","score":0.752582848072052}]
console.log(data[0].class)
```

Here is the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/vm9tu4bw/1/)

Comment: hi, I already try your code. It works on my other test. but this var data test, the result in console is "undefined". Is there any way?

Comment: Please elaborate your question briefly so i can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [{"loc":[7.876110076904297,48.79586219787598,577.145938873291,427.3995780944824],"class":"low","score":0.752582848072052}];

var json = data[0]["class"]

console.log(json);
```

Comment: hi, I already try your code. It works on my other test. but this var data test, the result in console is "undefined". Is there any way?

Comment: it returns actual result as of the property/key value, have you tried it within browser console?